# list as Python class variable

Tags: python

I want a class "Library" which has a class variable "books" which is a list of all the books in the library.  So may class begins

```
class Library:
    books = []
```

Now I want to add a book to my collection, but I can find no syntax
to do so.  The model I have in my head is something like

```
def addBook(self, book):
    books.append(book)
```

which I would expect to call with something like from the main routine with something like

```
lib = Library()
b = Book(author, title)
lib.addBook(b)
```

However, I've not been able to find any way to do this.  I always get an error with the "append" where I try to add the book to the list.

Comment: the way you are doing it, books is a class variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should declare `books` as an **instance variable**, not a *class variable*:

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self):
        self.books = []

    def addBook(self, book):
        self.books.append(book)
```

so you can create an *instance* of `Library`:

```
lib = Library()
b = Book(...)
lib.addBook(b)
```

**Notes:**

- For further information about `self` , you can read this [post](http://freepythontips.wordpress.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/).
- This assumes your `Book` class is implemented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

look at this [example](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks) for the initialization and the setter:

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self):
        self.books = []
    def add(self, x):
        self.books.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Library():
    def __init__(self):
        self.books = []
    def addBook(self, book):
        self.books.append(book)
```